# Plotting in julia: Lack of extensive and easily undestandable documentation?

Tags: matplotlib, julia, plots.jl

As a physics major I am by no means good at coding but it suffices for modeling stuff. Plotting always ends up a beeing super annoying. It´s easy enough to look up stuff in the the Julia documentation if needed.
With plotting it´s a totally different story. There is just no good ressources to learn handling the available plotting packages.

I´m lost. There is proper documentation for PyPlot for example but only for Python and the code won´t work in Julia. Then there a few examples that obivously do not answer all my questions. Am I missing something? I feel stupid but also know that everyone around me spends to much time on plotting, too.

Any advice on were to look up stuff?

thanks in advance

Comment: This post will likely be deleted since it’s asking for software suggestions which is against the code of conduct. Take a look at the Plots.jl or Makie.jl documentation. If something is not clear, raise and issue and ping me on GitHub and I will do my best to address it.

Comment: You are also welcome to join the Julia Slack: https://slackinvite.julialang.org/ where many plots users and Maintainers can answer potential questions.

Comment: If you edit this post to describe what you are actually trying to do with plots, maybe someone will be able to help!

Comment: @logankilpatrick I don't think the question is asking for recommendations of individual packages. It's a fair question that many new users struggle with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plotting in Julia is provided by packages. So you will not find plotting docs in the main documentation for julia.

There are a number of plotting packages to choose between - it's just a question of picking the one you prefer. Here is the documentation for most of the more used packages:

- Plots: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/
- Makie: https://makie.juliaplots.org/dev/
- PlotlyJS: http://spencerlyon.com/PlotlyJS.jl/
- VegaLite: https://www.queryverse.org/VegaLite.jl/stable/
- PGFPlotsX: https://kristofferc.github.io/PGFPlotsX.jl/dev/
- Gadfly: http://gadflyjl.org/stable/
- GR: https://gr-framework.org/julia.html
- UnicodePlots (for plotting in terminal): https://github.com/Evizero/UnicodePlots.jl

For PyPlot the matplotlib syntax should work. It's not clear from your question why it doesn't for you. So there should be ample resources.